# Botium box - Job queued for execution

Tags: javascript, bots, chatbot

I've recorded a series of 13 sample utterances in chatbots section
of botium box and saved the test cases .But it says job
queued for execution and is nearly waiting for long time to execute

[image: test case job sceduled]

[image: corresponding link info on click of read more button]

> 2019-06-17T12:14:43.199Z: Job queued for execution
>   2019-06-17T12:14:44.144Z: 2019-06-17T12:14:43.038Z
>   botium-box-worker-runtestcases Started processing, JobId #2122.
>
> 2019-06-17T12:14:44.273Z: 2019-06-17T12:14:43.053Z botium-BotDriver
>   Loaded Botium configuration file ./botium.json
>
> 2019-06-17T12:14:44.491Z: 2019-06-17T12:14:43.061Z botium-BotDriver
>   BuildCompiler: Capabilites: { PROJECTNAME: 'Test Project - vMMVv -
>   Test Session',   TEMPDIR: 'botiumwork',   CLEANUPTEMPDIR: true,
>   WAITFORBOTTIMEOUT: 10000,   SIMULATE_WRITING_SPEED: false,
>   DOCKERCOMPOSEPATH: 'docker-compose',   DOCKERMACHINEPATH:
>   'docker-machine',   DOCKERMACHINE: false,   DOCKERIMAGE: 'node:boron',
>   DOCKERUNIQUECONTAINERNAMES: false,   DOCKERSYSLOGPORT_RANGE:
>   '47100-47299',   BOT_HEALTH_STATUS: 200,   SLACK_PUBLISHPORT_RANGE:
>   '46100-46299',   FACEBOOK_PUBLISHPORT_RANGE: '46300-46499',
>   FACEBOOK_SEND_DELIVERY_CONFIRMATION: true,
>   BOTFRAMEWORK_PUBLISHPORT_RANGE: '46500-46699',
>   BOTFRAMEWORK_WEBHOOK_PORT: 3978,   BOTFRAMEWORK_WEBHOOK_PATH:
>   'api/messages',   BOTFRAMEWORK_CHANNEL_ID: 'facebook',
>   SIMPLEREST_PING_RETRIES: 6,   SIMPLEREST_PING_TIMEOUT: 10000,
>   SIMPLEREST_PING_VERB: 'GET',   SIMPLEREST_METHOD: 'GET',
>   WEBSPEECH_SERVER_PORT: 46050,   WEBSPEECH_LANGUAGE: 'en-US',
>   WEBSPEECH_CLOSEBROWSER: true,   SCRIPTING_TXT_EOL: '\n',
>   SCRIPTING_XLSX_EOL_SPLIT: '\r',   SCRIPTING_XLSX_EOL_WRITE: '\r\n',
>   SCRIPTING_XLSX_STARTROW: 2,   SCRIPTING_XLSX_STARTCOL: 1,
>   SCRIPTING_NORMALIZE_TEXT: true,   SCRIPTING_ENABLE_MEMORY: true,
>   SCRIPTING_MATCHING_MODE: 'includeLowerCase',
>   SCRIPTING_UTTEXPANSION_MODE: 'all',
>   SCRIPTING_UTTEXPANSION_RANDOM_COUNT: 1,
>   SCRIPTING_MEMORYEXPANSION_KEEP_ORIG: false,
>   RETRY_USERSAYS_ONERROR_REGEXP: [],   RETRY_USERSAYS_NUMRETRIES: 1,
>   RETRY_USERSAYS_FACTOR: 1,   RETRY_USERSAYS_MINTIMEOUT: 1000,
>   ASSERTERS:    [ { ref: 'HASLINK',
>          src: 'botium-asserter-basiclink',
>          global: false,
>          args: {} } ],   LOGIC_HOOKS: [],   USER_INPUTS: [],   ALEXA_SMAPI_API: 'simulation',   ALEXA_SMAPI_SKILLID:
>   'adminamzn1.ask.skill.4bf0188a-4dda-4810-b754-a3181193fbff',
>   ALEXA_SMAPI_LOCALE: 'en-US',   ALEXA_SMAPI_REFRESHTOKEN:
>   'Atzr|IwEBIEvgZitZhPSHNy3v7aEQ1OSZAW4iNAjaoHh2zH316H83ZjDZP0q-TFziI8TtVZDZDr-YW7dR7UQlulJ-Vx0aGkqtaSBaduYVVofaRqrQfJBcvA-4xBmbcfcFAD4pUORxqlx880Cr9-q_xup_9p5KHDhARFNlb7VIpxOc6l0XJkSb4_MtIdjZSH7JEHbBEjkYD9KOs6EzP8BYKHWiujrlmblXSe2e-DlFuTVlDJsH0nbKWAhVD8jha-Lbvhg8MNjcF5Ns1i-motmfPxNGPKyMCJcA6uXdduk2OSDUIJItMrJ6tbxB8_cMU1_0KJokGACvJcYptshW8r41DZrmVph1OUUmMGUlqSDRI54Z7Vx2Lqkx4ot1xJiR_FgAcWbt6TLYKpZtkVJf_Z5K21OZ5dPMUV41lR_EfHGhJnObQDWEUGswqAt4AYOfamXAqXfIktqHgdNMSOaU4DaHpu_Sr2PjrW8y7himvRrMIuhxDvJ4guezplhR1v5LZgr8cnoaaRg38prvDeAZ4FYgkUHFs866UsBGqaLXnslxjTyxPFg6zAxsCNc7LhhnzMdNBbilmqwYKUzysGL0MRi-6T5n6MGJag6TwOYZyszmxBRQQWrM_8oJL7WPo-3DRaPs8gjZLwLwodqrjP3GzBtyYQL6k97ka3Z8yD-U3wv_esGzcXCsoJy9lg',
>   ALEXA_SMAPI_ENDPOINTREGION: '',   CONTAINERMODE: 'alexa-smapi',
>   FBPAGERECEIVER_REDISURL: { port: '6379', host: 'redis', db: 0,
>   options: {} } }
>
> 2019-06-17T12:14:44.869Z: 2019-06-17T12:14:43.860Z
>   botium-ScriptingProvider Using matching mode: includeLowerCase
>
> 2019-06-17T12:14:44.999Z: 2019-06-17T12:14:43.861Z
>   botium-asserterUtils Loaded Default asserter - [ 'BUTTONS',   'MEDIA',
>   'PAUSE_ASSERTER',   'ENTITIES',   'ENTITY_VALUES',   'INTENT',
>   'INTENT_CONFIDENCE' ]
>
> 2019-06-17T12:14:45.108Z: 2019-06-17T12:14:43.861Z
>   botium-asserterUtils Loaded Default logic hook - [ 'PAUSE',
>   'WAITFORBOT',   'SET_SCRIPTING_MEMORY',   'CLEAR_SCRIPTING_MEMORY',
>   'INCLUDE' ]
>
> 2019-06-17T12:14:45.519Z: 2019-06-17T12:14:43.862Z
>   botium-asserterUtils Loaded Default user input - [ 'BUTTON', 'MEDIA',
>   'FORM' ]
>
> 2019-06-17T12:14:45.628Z: 2019-06-17T12:14:43.863Z
>   botium-asserterUtils Trying to load HASLINK asserter from
>   botium-asserter-basiclink
>
> 2019-06-17T12:14:45.756Z: 2019-06-17T12:14:44.089Z
>   botium-asserterUtils Loaded HASLINK SUCCESSFULLY
>
> 2019-06-17T12:14:45.884Z: 2019-06-17T12:14:44.116Z
>   botium-box-worker-runtestcases expanding convos ...
>
> 2019-06-17T12:14:46.002Z: 2019-06-17T12:14:44.116Z
>   botium-ScriptingProvider ExpandConvos - Using utterances expansion
>   mode: all
>
> 2019-06-17T12:14:46.117Z: 2019-06-17T12:14:44.119Z
>   botium-box-worker-runtestcases found 1 convos ...
>
> 2019-06-17T12:14:46.247Z: 2019-06-17T12:14:44.120Z
>   botium-box-worker-runtestcases batchNum: 1 batchCount: 1
>   convosPerBatch: 1 batchStart: 0 batchEnd: 0 batchLength: 1
>
> 2019-06-17T12:14:46.361Z: 2019-06-17T12:14:44.122Z botium-BotDriver
>   Build - Botium Core Version: 1.4.13
>
> 2019-06-17T12:14:46.567Z: 2019-06-17T12:14:44.122Z botium-BotDriver
>   Build - Capabilites: { PROJECTNAME: 'Test Project - vMMVv - Test
>   Session',   TEMPDIR: 'botiumwork',   CLEANUPTEMPDIR: true,
>   WAITFORBOTTIMEOUT: 10000,   SIMULATE_WRITING_SPEED: false,
>   DOCKERCOMPOSEPATH: 'docker-compose',   DOCKERMACHINEPATH:
>   'docker-machine',   DOCKERMACHINE: false,   DOCKERIMAGE: 'node:boron',
>   DOCKERUNIQUECONTAINERNAMES: false,   DOCKERSYSLOGPORT_RANGE:
>   '47100-47299',   BOT_HEALTH_STATUS: 200,   SLACK_PUBLISHPORT_RANGE:
>   '46100-46299',   FACEBOOK_PUBLISHPORT_RANGE: '46300-46499',
>   FACEBOOK_SEND_DELIVERY_CONFIRMATION: true,
>   BOTFRAMEWORK_PUBLISHPORT_RANGE: '46500-46699',
>   BOTFRAMEWORK_WEBHOOK_PORT: 3978,   BOTFRAMEWORK_WEBHOOK_PATH:
>   'api/messages',   BOTFRAMEWORK_CHANNEL_ID: 'facebook',
>   SIMPLEREST_PING_RETRIES: 6,   SIMPLEREST_PING_TIMEOUT: 10000,
>   SIMPLEREST_PING_VERB: 'GET',   SIMPLEREST_METHOD: 'GET',
>   WEBSPEECH_SERVER_PORT: 46050,   WEBSPEECH_LANGUAGE: 'en-US',
>   WEBSPEECH_CLOSEBROWSER: true,   SCRIPTING_TXT_EOL: '\n',
>   SCRIPTING_XLSX_EOL_SPLIT: '\r',   SCRIPTING_XLSX_EOL_WRITE: '\r\n',
>   SCRIPTING_XLSX_STARTROW: 2,   SCRIPTING_XLSX_STARTCOL: 1,
>   SCRIPTING_NORMALIZE_TEXT: true,   SCRIPTING_ENABLE_MEMORY: true,
>   SCRIPTING_MATCHING_MODE: 'includeLowerCase',
>   SCRIPTING_UTTEXPANSION_MODE: 'all',
>   SCRIPTING_UTTEXPANSION_RANDOM_COUNT: 1,
>   SCRIPTING_MEMORYEXPANSION_KEEP_ORIG: false,
>   RETRY_USERSAYS_ONERROR_REGEXP: [],   RETRY_USERSAYS_NUMRETRIES: 1,
>   RETRY_USERSAYS_FACTOR: 1,   RETRY_USERSAYS_MINTIMEOUT: 1000,
>   ASSERTERS:    [ { ref: 'HASLINK',
>          src: 'botium-asserter-basiclink',
>          global: false,
>          args: {} } ],   LOGIC_HOOKS: [],   USER_INPUTS: [],   ALEXA_SMAPI_API: 'simulation',   ALEXA_SMAPI_SKILLID:
>   'adminamzn1.ask.skill.4bf0188a-4dda-4810-b754-a3181193fbff',
>   ALEXA_SMAPI_LOCALE: 'en-US',   ALEXA_SMAPI_REFRESHTOKEN:
>   'Atzr|IwEBIEvgZitZhPSHNy3v7aEQ1OSZAW4iNAjaoHh2zH316H83ZjDZP0q-TFziI8TtVZDZDr-YW7dR7UQlulJ-Vx0aGkqtaSBaduYVVofaRqrQfJBcvA-4xBmbcfcFAD4pUORxqlx880Cr9-q_xup_9p5KHDhARFNlb7VIpxOc6l0XJkSb4_MtIdjZSH7JEHbBEjkYD9KOs6EzP8BYKHWiujrlmblXSe2e-DlFuTVlDJsH0nbKWAhVD8jha-Lbvhg8MNjcF5Ns1i-motmfPxNGPKyMCJcA6uXdduk2OSDUIJItMrJ6tbxB8_cMU1_0KJokGACvJcYptshW8r41DZrmVph1OUUmMGUlqSDRI54Z7Vx2Lqkx4ot1xJiR_FgAcWbt6TLYKpZtkVJf_Z5K21OZ5dPMUV41lR_EfHGhJnObQDWEUGswqAt4AYOfamXAqXfIktqHgdNMSOaU4DaHpu_Sr2PjrW8y7himvRrMIuhxDvJ4guezplhR1v5LZgr8cnoaaRg38prvDeAZ4FYgkUHFs866UsBGqaLXnslxjTyxPFg6zAxsCNc7LhhnzMdNBbilmqwYKUzysGL0MRi-6T5n6MGJag6TwOYZyszmxBRQQWrM_8oJL7WPo-3DRaPs8gjZLwLwodqrjP3GzBtyYQL6k97ka3Z8yD-U3wv_esGzcXCsoJy9lg',
>   ALEXA_SMAPI_ENDPOINTREGION: '',   CONTAINERMODE: 'alexa-smapi',
>   FBPAGERECEIVER_REDISURL: { port: '6379', host: 'redis', db: 0,
>   options: {} } }
>
> 2019-06-17T12:14:46.763Z: 2019-06-17T12:14:44.123Z botium-BotDriver
>   Build - Sources : { LOCALPATH: '.',   GITPATH: 'git',   GITBRANCH:
>   'master',   GITDIR: '.' }
>
> 2019-06-17T12:14:46.915Z: 2019-06-17T12:14:44.123Z botium-BotDriver
>   Build - Envs : { IS_BOTIUM_CONTAINER: true }
>
> 2019-06-17T12:14:48.284Z: 2019-06-17T12:14:48.206Z
>   botium-PluginConnectorContainer Botium plugin
>   botium-connector-alexa-smapi loaded
>
> 2019-06-17T12:14:48.374Z: 2019-06-17T12:14:48.207Z
>   botium-connector-alexa-smapi Validate called
>
> 2019-06-17T12:14:48.463Z: 2019-06-17T12:14:48.210Z
>   botium-connector-alexa-smapi Build called
>
> 2019-06-17T12:14:48.752Z: 2019-06-17T12:14:48.211Z
>   botium-connector-alexa-smapi Start called
>
> 2019-06-17T12:14:48.880Z: 2019-06-17T12:14:48.212Z
>   botium-box-worker-runtestcases Running Convo "Myplanfeatures_Alexa",
>   Index 0, 1 from 1
>
> 2019-06-17T12:14:49.020Z: 2019-06-17T12:14:48.232Z botium-Convo
>   Myplanfeatures_Alexa/Line 3: user says {   "sender": "me",
>   "channel": null,   "messageText": "bye",   "stepTag": "Line 3",
>   "not": false,   "asserters": [],   "logicHooks": [],   "userInputs":
>   [] }
>
> 2019-06-17T12:14:49.130Z: 2019-06-17T12:14:48.234Z
>   botium-connector-alexa-smapi UserSays called

Answer (score 0):

You can see if the Botium Agent is online by switching to the *Agents* view, you should see a recent heartbeat there (agents are sending a "I'm online" heartbeat every few seconds):

[image]

If the agent is not online, you have find out why - best way is to have a look at the [docker logs](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/29360129/Enable+Diagnostics+and+Inspect+Logs).

Comment: Here's the log of my test case

Comment: There is a known bug in the Alexa-Smapi connector, that the Botium Agent crashes when the connection to the Skill Management API is failing - the fix that the agent won't crash is included in the next build, but this won't fix the connectivity problem - with the next build there will be more information in the log in those cases (instead of crashing).

Comment: How to proceed now .Is there a work around or should I create test cases with few no of utterrances like for eg: 4 or 5 .Plus how to we know if " Skill Management API is failing" .

Comment: This is the error message:

Response body: {"message":"1 validation error detected: Value 'adminamzn1.ask.skill.4bf0188a-4dda-4810-b754-a3181193fbff' at 'skillStageIdentifiers.1.member.skillId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: (^amzn1\\.ask\\.skill\\.[0-9a-f\\-]+)|(^amzn1\\.echo-sdk-ams\\.app\\.[0-9a-f\\-]+)"}

Comment: Please upgrade to the latest Botium Box version to stop your agent crashing on invalid Alexa credentials.

Comment: How do i Update the version .
Can i use the below steps

> curl --output docker-compose-all.yml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codeforequity-at/botium-box-basic-dist/master/docker-compose-all.yml

> docker-compose -f docker-compose-all.yml up

Comment: Do a "docker-compose -f docker-compose-all.yml pull" before the "up"

Comment: I would suggest you to create a Gitter page for botium .

Comment: currently evaluating what tool to use for community chat